# Какие есть слова в русском языке с неоднозначным ударением?

Tags: орфоэпия

Хочется понять, какие в русском языке есть слова (базовые формы), в которых возможно неоднозначное ударение. Меняется ли при этом смысл слова - не важно. Я сходу могу назвать следующие:

- творОг, твОрог
- замОк, зАмок
- костюмИрованный, костюмирОванный *(устар.)*
- свЁкла, свеклА *(разг.)*
- пулОвер, пуловЕр *(разг.)*

Ещё крутилось единоврЕменно, единовремЕнно, но по ним сейчас словарь даёт однозначное ударение.

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите в Википедии статью [Омографы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%8B) - найдете множество примеров.

> Омо́графы (от др.-греч. ὁμός — «одинаковый» и γράφω — «пишу») — слова, которые совпадают в написании, но различаются в произношении (в русском языке чаще всего из-за различий в ударении).